# When should a golfing language question be posted here vs. on CGCC?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, code-golf, golfing-languages, site-recommendation

There are currently two sites where questions about golfing languages (languages designed to be as compact as possible) are definitively on-topic:

- This site
- [Code Golf & Coding Challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design)

What should be considered when deciding whether to post a golflang question here vs. on CGCC?

Answer (score 11):

## Rough heuristic: Is it golfing-specific?

The main difference between posting here vs. on CGCC will be who sees your question. On CGCC, it'll be people who primarily golf, in a variety of languages, so you'll likely be getting feedback primarily through the lens of golfiness. On PLDI, however, you'll be surrounded by an audience of more general language designers and implementers, so you'll likely get better answers regarding parsing, interpreting, and other topics which apply to all languages.

Thus, if your question would benefit from detailed discussion of golfiness, it may be better on CGCC (but is perfectly fine here!), and if it would benefit more from advice from langdevs from a variety of backgrounds, it may be better here (but is perfectly fine on CGCC).

Comment: The problem is that if you ask a question related to golfing languages on CGCC, it's probably going to be marked as duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/198446/tips-for-creating-maintaining-a-golfing-language) question.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think you'll get better advice on PLDI. Golflangs are basically spin-offs of practical languages, except the more common builtins and syntaxes are shortened.

So if you post the question on PLDI, the answers are generally going to be better since there are more people who are familiar with a lot of languages, and will answer your question better. Whereas in CGCC, most people only work with toy tasks and might not have the expertise  of the PLDI users.

Answer (score 0):

If a question is asking "how do I make my language shorter" then Code Golf is where it goes.

If a question is asking "how do I design a language in an unconventional way" or "how do I implement language feature" then here is where it goes.

Unconventional here meaning that the syntax of the language isn't what you'd expect from a prac-lang.

### Examples

Assuming the language is [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage):

- What chaining rules make sense? - belongs here, because it's asking about syntax
- What chaining rules lead to the shortest program? - belongs on code golf
- What are the pros and cons of using an arity-based tacit system? - belongs here
- Is an arity based tacit system golfy? - belongs on code golf